# Ajax accordion headers some links and some not

Tags: c#, header, accordion

I'm using an ajax toolkit accorion bound to a SiteMapDataSource. Some of the nodes which are bound to accordion headers are links and some are not. The SuppressHeaderPostbacks property sets all of the headers either true or false meaning not causing postback in otherwords not acting as a link, or false meaning causing postback in otherwords acting like a link. Is it possible to set only some of the headers to act as links?

EDIT:My problem is that some of the webSiteMap nodes have child nodes and some don't. The ones that don't have child nodes have urls of their own but the ones that have child nodes don't have urls of their own. So I want those that don't have child nodes to to be headers & links (but they don't open up because they have no child nodes) but those that do have child nodes I want to be headers opening up to show child nodes but not being links so not causing postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorganizing my website map solved the problem. I'm making new parent nodes which are not links and making all nodes which are links into child nodes. All the parent nodes are not links. That way I can set the SuppressHeaderPostbacks property to true and none of the headers are links and only the items in the expansion are links.